# if two vars share the same reference to a non-primitive type why doesn't this code work

Tags: javascript

I am currently dealing with understanding how values are assigned and passed around in Javascript. Primitive type's values are passed by value-copy, and object value types are passed by reference-copy.

If that is the case then why does this line of code not  cause "yourAddress" variable to change the property of "street" to "321 cba street"?

```js
var myAddress = {
  street: "123 abc st",
};
var yourAddress = myAddress;
myAddress = { street: "321 cba street" }; // doesn't change the val
myAddress.street = "321 cba street"; // doesn't change the val
console.log(yourAddress.street);
```

Why doesn't re-assigning the variable, or modifying the property name affect also the output of yourAddress.street since it has the same reference as myAddress.

Is the reason for this hoisting or am I not understanding something here internally with JS?

The version of this code that would work is this but why?

```js
var myAddress = {
  street: "123 abc st",
};
myAddress = { street: "321 cba street" }; // doesn't change the val
myAddress.street = "321 cba street"; // doesn't change the val

var yourAddress = myAddress;

console.log(yourAddress.street);
```

Comment: edited my question, it was incoherent.

Comment: re-assigning and modifying are two different things. If two variables have same reference and one of them is **modified(not re-assigned)** then the other will also change.

Comment: The second assignment to `myAddress` assigns a new, different object. After that, the two variables do **not** reference the same object.

Comment: This could be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference

Comment: I see why is this allowed in JS? Isn't this a duplicate variable declaration?

Comment: The variable is declared only once; when it is prefixed by the `var` keyword. You just reassign it.

Comment: Thank you, I am understanding better, I guess undeclared and declared function is create a new reference somewhere in memory, so when I made another declaration with the same variable name myAddress, the yourAddress doesn't hold the same reference, myAddress is now stored as a new point in memory.

Comment: @FZs yeah same question.

Answer (score 5):

```
myAddress = { street: "321 cba street" }; // doesn't change the val
```

Yes, because this reassigns `myAddress` to point to a totally different object from `yourAddress`, so of course changes made thereafter to `myAddress` won't reflect to `yourAddress`. It's as if `yourAddress = myAddress` never happened.

Going back to the beginning of the program:

```
var myAddress = {
  street: "123 abc st",
};
var yourAddress = myAddress;
```

At this point, here's what the vars point to:

```
.------------------.
| object in memory | <------------ myAddress
`------------------`
         ^
         +------------------------ yourAddress
```

Then after the next line executes:

```
myAddress = { street: "321 cba street" }; // doesn't change the val
```

we have:

```
.------------------.
| object in memory | <------------ myAddress
`------------------`
.------------------.
| object in memory | <------------ yourAddress
`------------------`
```

These are two totally distinct objects being referenced by separate variables.

Remove the reassignment to `myAddress` and you'll see the change to the single object as accessed by multiple variables as you expect.

```js
var myAddress = {street: "123 abc st"};
var yourAddress = myAddress;
myAddress.street = "321 cba street";
console.log(yourAddress.street, myAddress.street);
```

This situation (two references to one object in memory) is fundamentally the same as making a function call with an object parameter. A new variable is created on the function stack, but it's not a copy of the object; it's just a reference to the same underlying data.

```js
var fn = param => {
  param.street = 42;
};

var myAddress = {street: "123 abc st"};
fn(myAddress);
console.log(myAddress.street);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already understand, non-primitive variables only hold a reference. This reference works just like any primitive type (*only the reference, **not** the object*): it can be copied, and reassigned without changing the other reference. So, in this code, `foo.bar` will still be 2:

```
let foo = {bar: 2};
let bar = foo;
bar = {bar: 5};
console.log(foo.bar);
```

The reference is copied just like any primitive type; the difference is that you can change an object through a reference.